# "Back to top" button does not hide when tapping on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I have a simple "back to top" button that is fixed to the bottom left corner that fades in when the user scrolls past a certain point and hides when the user clicks the button or scrolls back to the top.  That part works fine.  However on mobile, if I tap the button, it not only activates the hover pseudo class and tooltip but actually remains in that state even after it scrolls back to the top.  I imagine there is some extra code I need to add to cover touch functionality but that is the part I don't know.

Here is the link to one of the portfolio pages on my site that uses the button: [www.nickolder.com/banknote.html](http://www.nickolder.com/banknote.html)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ndsh7sgw/)

```js
var $btt = $('.back_to_top');

// Scroll to top when user clicks back-to-top button
$btt.on('click', function (e) {

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 1200);

  e.preventDefault();

});

// Show / hide back-to-top button depending on scroll position
$(window).on('scroll', function() {

  var self = $(this),
      height = self.height(),
      top = self.scrollTop();

  if ( top > height ) {
    if ($btt.css('opacity') !== 1) {
      $btt.removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
    }
  } else {
    $btt.removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
  }

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  color: white;
}

p:last-of-type {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

div {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(20,230,170,1), rgba(20, 170, 230, 1));
  height: 3000px;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
}

.back_to_top {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 3;
 height: 40px;
 width: 40px;
 bottom: 20px;
 left: 20px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 opacity: 0.7;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(204,27,48,1), rgba(109,13,199,1.00));
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(204,27,48,1), rgba(109,13,199,1.00));
 background: -o-linear-gradient(to top, rgba(204,27,48,1), rgba(109,13,199,1.00));
 background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(204,27,48,1), rgba(109,13,199,1.00));
}

.back_to_top:hover {
 opacity: 1;
 box-shadow: 0 6px 12px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 transform: translateY(-3px);
}

.back_to_top,
.back_to_top:hover {
 transition: 0.3s ease;
 will-change: transform, opacity;
}

.back_to_top::before,
.back_to_top::after {
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
 pointer-events: none;
 will-change: opacity, transform;
}

.back_to_top::before {
 content: 'Back to top';
 color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
 background-color: rgba(20,25,30,1);
 border-radius: 4px;
 width: 100px;
 padding: 8px;
 text-align: center;
 left: 150%;
 top: 3px;
}

.back_to_top::after {
 border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid rgba(20,25,30,1);
  border-top: 6px solid transparent;
 left: 130%;
 bottom: 13px;
 width: 0;
 content: '';
}

.back_to_top:hover::before,
.back_to_top:hover::after {
 opacity: 1;
 transform: translateX(-6px);
 transition: 0.4s 0.4s ease;
 will-change: opacity, transform;
}

.hide {
 opacity: 0;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.show {
 opacity: 0.7;
}

.hide,
.show {
 transition: 0.6s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Top</p>
  <p>Bottom</p>
  <a href="#" class="back_to_top hide"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Might not be what you want but can you not just add `$btt.removeClass('show').addClass('hide');` in the click event handler?

Comment: when you say "on mobile" please be specific about the browser.

Comment: I tried that with no luck.  I think it has something to do with the default behavior for tap input on hover states.  Even when I try tapping anywhere else in the body, the hover state remains active on the button until I scroll all the way back down and tap off.

Comment: This is with iOS Safari

Comment: This is why its recommended to follow a **mobile-first approach**. In this case you need to remove/reverse the hover effect applied on larger device widths using `@media` queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of the `@media hover:hover` media query to restrict the styles to devices that support `:hover` **completely** (ones equip with a mouse or certain pointing devices)

Wrap all your hover styles within this.

```
@media (hover:hover) {
  .back_to_top:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    transform: translateY(-3px);
  }

  .back_to_top,
  .back_to_top:hover {
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    will-change: transform, opacity;
  }

  .back_to_top:hover::before,
  .back_to_top:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(-6px);
    transition: 0.4s 0.4s ease;
    will-change: opacity, transform;
  }
}
```

[Your Fiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/ndsh7sgw/4/)

Conversely you could also target devices that do not support `:hover` completely.

```
@media (hover:none), (hover:on-demand) { ... }
```